# Running a python file on sublime text because it is importing C language libraries?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, sublimetext3

I'm trying to run a simple python hello file program but sublime text doesn't recognize file format; treating it as linker script because its importing g++/gcc bin libraries on windows 10

***this is the error message***

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:C:\Users\Manish\Desktop\test2.py: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:C:\Users\Manish\Desktop\test2.py:1: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "C:\Users\Manish\Desktop\test2.py" -o "C:\Users\Manish\Desktop/test2" && "C:\Users\Manish\Desktop/test2"]
[dir: C:\Users\Manish\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;F:\Software\MATLAB\R2016a\runtime\win64;F:\Software\MATLAB\R2016a\bin;F:\Software\MATLAB\R2016a\polyspace\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;G:\College\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Manish\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin;C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Manish\Desktop;]
```

Comment: Seems like you've set the syntax of the file to be C/C++ as `g++` or cygwin is not needed for running Python files

Comment: How am I suppose to remove that syntax temporarily for python programming because sometimes I need to run c++ file too

Comment: I mean to say to disable cygwin temporarily so that I can run python code and when needed run c++ code

Comment: set `Tools -> Build System -> Automatic`

Comment: Sublime should recognize and determine which commands are run based on the file extenstion, such as `.py`, or `.c`, but if you have somehow modified that setting, then it won't do that.

Comment: Thanks @venky__  it worked .